# Is it possible to ignore an equation in a Differential Equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose we have $\dot{x}=f(x,y)$ and $L(x,y)=0$ where $L$ can be A complicated expression, for example might have integrals and derivates inside it. My question is this: Suppose I know what $y$ is (You can assume it is a guess we are sure about or whatever), Can I look at only
$$\dot{x}=f(x,y)$$
and solve it ? (Both x,y are functions of a scalar $t$) Is this legit?
Update: To say more about what I'm doing in my specific problem.
\begin{equation*}
y(t) =  - \frac{x(t)}{1-\dot{x}(t)},
\end{equation*}
and the other one(L) is complicated. Can we use this?:
\begin{align*}
x (t) =  \int_{0}^{t}  \exp \left( - \int_{t}^{s} \frac{1}{y(\tau)} d\tau \right) ds.
\end{align*}
and hence

\begin{align*}
x (t) =   \int_{0}^{t}  \exp \left(  \int_{t}^{s} \frac{1-\dot{x}(\tau)}{x(\tau)} d\tau \right) ds.
\end{align*}
I know that the last equation is implicit but that is fine for my purpose. At least it doesn't have $y$. Is my analysis legit?

Comment: If you magically know what $y$ is then the equation for $x$ is now "effectively autonomous". In practice this is extremely unlikely to actually happen with a constraint problem like this.

Comment: For constrained problems one usually have to use Lagrange multiplier or some other method. Howeveras @Ian has already stated, if you know $y$ you can reduce your problem to an ODE in $x$. However you still need to  make sure the constraint is valid.

Comment: @Ian  I have now included the specific f. Is my analysis legit?

Comment: Well now you seemingly have too many equations; if $y$ is just a function of $x$ and $\dot{x}$ then your equation without the $L$ is already in the form $F(x,\dot{x})=0$ which will "typically" already have a unique solution. It might not actually depending on what $f$ is but you don't have the freedom to just impose this $L(x,y)=0$ condition and expect a solution to exist.

Comment: It might help if you posted the full context of the problem.